# How do I load a model method into a controller constructor in CodeIgniter?

Tags: codeigniter, model, constructor

I am trying to extend the CI_Controller class to load my global page header file so I don't have to load it at the beginning of every single controller method.  It doesn't seem to be working.  I know the Controller extension itself works... if I remove the call of the model method from the constructor and load it from my controller method, the rest of the controller extension works fine.  But when I load the model method from within the constructor of the controller extension, I get a blank page(I haven't generated the main content yet).

Any ideas?

application/core/MY_Controller.php

```
<?php
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

    var $user = array();

    function __construct(){

        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('member');

        if($this->session->userdata('member_id')){

            $this->member->get_info($this->session->userdata('member_id'));
            $this->user = $this->member->info;
            $this->member->update_activity($this->session->userdata('member_id'));

        } else {

            $this->load->helper('cookie');

            if(get_cookie('Teacher Tools Member Cookie')){

                $this->member->auto_login(get_cookie('Teacher Tools Member Cookie'));

            } else {

                $this->user = $this->member->default_info();
            }

        }

        $this->load->model('template');
        $this->template->overall_header();
    }
}
```

application/models/template.php

```
<?php

class Template extends MY_Model {

    function __construct(){

    parent::__construct();

}

function overall_header($title = 'Home'){

    $data = array(
        'BASE_URL' => base_url(),
        'MAIN_NAVIGATION' => $this->main_navigation(),
        'TOOLBAR' => $this->toolbar()
    );

    return $this->parser->parse('overall_header.tpl', $data);

}
```

MY_Model is an extension of the CI_Model class to load member information into $this->user.

Comment: also post the `member model` code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think response generation is done in Controller's method and all HTML pieces that you might have gets glued there. So if you are calling `/controller/method_a` then `method_a` will be responsible for returning response whereas in constructor you cannot set response.

I agree with you on setting important data in Constructor once so that you don't have to do this again and again in each method. I think you should assign output to some Controller level `variable` and then use that `variable` in your Controller's method.

I' am sure you got my point.

Answer (score 0):

For this reason there is a config/autoload.php:

```
$autoload['model'] = array('YourModel');
```